# Why ContinueWhenAll hides unobserved exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library

When I call `ContinueWhenAll(...)` unobserved exception from task is fully hidden. `UnobservedTaskException` event is not raised and application is not killed. I wait for several hours.
Of course I place the following

```
<runtime>
    <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

into the config file.

If I comment `ContinueWhenAll` call - event is raised and application is killed very quickly. And also simple continuation `ContinueWith` does not hide unobserved exception too.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From unobserved exception handler: {0}", e.Exception.Message);
        };

    var faultedTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception("Task is faulted"); });

    // 1. ContinueWhenAll hides unobserved exception
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new Task[] { faultedTask }, ts =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From \"when all\" continuation");
    });

    // 2. Simple continuation does not hide unobserved exception
    //faultedTask.ContinueWith(t => { Console.WriteLine("From \"simple\" continuation"); });

    faultedTask = null;
    int gcCounter = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        // artifical memory consumption
        int[][] a = new int[4096][];
        for (int j = 0; j < 4096; j++ )
            a[j] = new int[4096];

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        Console.WriteLine("Garbage collected: {0}", ++gcCounter);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Continuations will not observe exceptions themselves. And stephen's [comment here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx?PageIndex=2) says the same. *Continuations do not observe the Task's exception, and that includes ContinueWhenAll.  An easy way to force observation is to add a call to Task.WaitAll as the first line in your ContinueWhenAll's delegate; at that point the tasks are all completed, so you're just taking advantage of WaitAll's observation logic.* So I'm not sure what's happening. Edit: updated my comment

Answer (score 1):

Your test is problematic. I didn't manage to get an `UnobservedTaskException` even with `Task.ContinueWith` however when I extracted the part firing the tasks to a different method the event is raised on both `Task.ContinueWith` **and** `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll` (as Sriram Sakthivel pointed out, building in release mode also has the same effect):

```
static void Main()
{
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From unobserved exception handler: {0}", e.Exception.Message);
    };

    RunTask();

    int gcCounter = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        // artifical memory consumption
        int[][] a = new int[4096][];
        for (int j = 0; j < 4096; j++)
            a[j] = new int[4096];

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        Console.WriteLine("Garbage collected: {0}", ++gcCounter);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}

static void RunTask()
{
    var faultedTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception("Task is faulted"); });

    // 1. ContinueWhenAll hides unobserved exception
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { faultedTask }, ts =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From \"when all\" continuation");
    });

    // 2. Simple continuation does not hide unobserved exception
    //faultedTask.ContinueWith(t => { Console.WriteLine("From \"simple\" continuation"); });
}
```

So, the reason you didn't get that exception is simply that the `Task` wasn't GCed yet.

Comment: Just tested, it is because of the fact that OP (and myself) isn't running with release mode. You don't need a separate method. Just running in release mode is enough.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel indeed. In release mode both raise the event. In any case, it's always consistent with `ContinueWith`

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are right. The only reason the event is not raised is the task is not GC'ed. I think there is a some special behavior in the TPL for assemblies compiled for debug and\or under debugger. I see something like that in disassembled TPL code, but I don't understand it exactly right now. May be it's related to support of "Tasks" window in VS.

Comment: @AntonK TPL was already compiled. The difference is in your code being compiled in release or debug. But yes, it's probably for debug windows.